# Join Red Hat Linux 6 to a Windows Active Directory Domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, redhat, pam

I am using Red Hat 6 (for testing purpose) and configure samba with active directory.Red Hat 6 has successfully join with my windows server 2003 domain. By typing the command

```
[root@mainserver /] # net ads join -U Administrator
Enter Administrator's password
using short domain name - - PDC
join 'MAINSERVER' to dns domain 'pdc.local'
[root@mainserver /] #
```

By this command

wbinfo -u

I can see all users which are created in my windows server 2003.

When I type the command

```
[root@mainserver /] # wbinfo -a test % password
Enter test's password:
plaintext password authentication succeeded
Enter test's password:
Challenge/response password authentication succeeded
[root@mainserver /]
```

it also successfully update the password.
Well I did all these configuration from a web site

https://www.linux-answered.com/2012/05/06/how-to-join-a-debian-6-to-a-windows-active-directory-domain/

I have done my working till "Step 6 joining the domain " according to the web site and it did successfully

## There is a step "Edit the PAM settings" .In my Red Hat 6 I can not see these following files

```
/etc/pam.d/common-account
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
/etc/pam.d/common-password
/etc/pam.d/common-session
```

All these are for Ubuntu/Debian server.

**My question is in Red Hat these configuration file are not available but may be it is available with other name inside**

/etc/pam.d/

Please just highlight the file?

**2- My second question is what is the purpose of these files inside /etc/pam.d ?**

thanks

Answer (score 2):

PAM and the files in pam.d integrate multiple low-level authentication schemes into a high-level application programming interface (API). It allows programs that rely on authentication to be written independently of the underlying authentication scheme.

Altering these files tells the system to look at Active Directory as part of the authentication process.  Perhaps you want to alter the "login" file?  However, I wouldn't mess around with these unless you understand what you're adding and where to place it.

Another option would be to make use of SSSD.  Red Hat has the process well documented and you're already at least half way there.

Configuration #3 is probably comparable to what you're trying to to:
http://www.redhat.com/en/resources/integrating-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

> All these are for Ubuntu/Debian server.
>
> ```
> /etc/pam.d/common-account
> /etc/pam.d/common-auth
> /etc/pam.d/common-password
> /etc/pam.d/common-session
> ```
>
> My question is in Red Hat these configuration file are not available but may be it is available with other name

You are looking for `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`. These files each have the 'account', 'auth', 'password', and 'session' stanzas from the Ubuntu 'common-*' file. (Look at the names of the files, and compare the contents of these two files.)

You will want to edit both, because one service may use the `password-auth` file. (SSH - Look in `/etc/pam.d/ssh` and see how it includes `password-auth`.) And another may use `system-auth` (Gnome, etc.)

[I'll also echo](https://serverfault.com/a/665037/50647) that there are easier ways of doing this in EL6. You really shouldn't have to touch these files by hand to the extent that the linked how-to is expecting.